# Filter nodes only with relationship type

Tags: neo4j

This is probably something really simple I'm missing but how can I filter nodes only with a relationship type .

Let's say I have the following nodes and relationships:
  m:Movie-[actedin]->p:person
  m:Movie-[director]->p:person

If I do a match query using :
    m:Movie-[actedin]->p:person

I get back persons who directed as well. How can I filter it so that only person labels who have the actedin relationship are returned ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It was really simple, I forgot the colon. It works without the colon, it just ignores the relationship

```
m:Movie-[actedin]->p:person

m:Movie- [:actedin]->p:person 
          ^
```

Comment: In the version without the colon it will match all relationships from a movie to a person of any type and store the them in a variable called actedin that you can them reference or return. You could also use use the form [varname:actedin] to match the relationship type and store to a variable.